# Targeting nested object properties inside an parent object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to change the state of opening/closing times (and the post to an endpoint) on multiple days which are return to me in an object like so:

[image]

I have rendered these in a React component:

```
{this.state.time.map(each => (
    <Fragment key={each.code}>
        <OpeningHours
            code={each.code}
            day={each.description}
            name={each.code}
            open={each.open !== null ? each.open : '00:00'}
            close={each.close !== null ? each.close : '00:00'}
            onChange={this.onTimeChange}
        />
    </Fragment>
))}
```

[image]

How would I iterate through the array of objects until I find the index of either the opening or closing time of `this` day? So far I've tried this, which works, but only if there was, say, just an opening time or one field in general. The issue arises since I have 2 fields to edit:

```
onTimeChange(e) {
  let inputs = this.state.inputs.slice();
  for(let i in inputs){
      if(inputs[i].name == event.target.name){
          inputs[i].value = event.target.value;
          this.setState ({inputs});
          break;
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: You can use .filter(). https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Answer (score 0):

```
 const newInputs = inputs.map(p =>

      p.name === <unique_name/code>
        ? { ...p, [e.target.name]: e.target.value }
        : p
    );
    this.setState({inputs:newInputs,});
```

Change the onTimeChange() method to get the unique_name:`onTimeChange(e, code)`

A simple example: https://codesandbox.io/s/v1y14rl2oy

Since index is unique, you can do

`inputs[index] = { ...inputs[index], [e.target.name]: e.target.value }`
too without using `map()` as in the sandbox.

Comment: Interesting. Didn't think of using `.filter()`. How would this look setting the state syntax-wise? I would assume I'd need to create a copy of the current state by using spread? Right now, this returns an empty array:

`const times = this.state.time;
 const results = times.filter(time => time.code === e.target.value);
 console.log(results);`

Comment: See above for the issue I'm facing

Comment: think I misunderstood the question. So you want to find the array with the particular input.name and then change the related fields for the object with that name or what?

Comment: The opening and closing hours will both be editable and all day objects have an opening and closing property (all day objects are nested in another object called `opening_hours`) the properties are named `open` and `close` see the screenshot of the logged object above. I need to be able to edit both opening and closing individually for every day and set the new state to say, if I edit (by user input) `Tuesday` `open` to 05:00 then it will change the state to, what it was before but only change `tues` `open` to 05:00.

Comment: It's definitely very close, it's just that in your `list` object you have added `name=name0 name=name1` etc, whereas my object `code` property doesn't return with its index. @Asteriscus

Comment: You don't need index. That was just an example. 
Is your `code` property not unique? If not how would you know to update the particular day then.

Comment: You need to pass a property that makes sure the object you are going to update belongs to the particular day in your `onChange` function.